# Multi Website, Different Prices, Same Domain?

Tags: price, multicurrency, scope, domain

We're after a multi currency, multi price, multi national Magento website **on a single .com domain.**

The key point is that the client wants to have different product prices on each website. Fine, product price scope set to 'Website'.

The problem is, **can we use just one domain to service all of this?** How will this work on the front end? Will Magento work nicely out of the box with this set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, you can't set the scope to store/website level for a product. You have to manage this by editing the price for each store-view.

When you edit the price per view, magento will properly override the default data with the one you defined in the view.

For the problem with multiple stores on one domain: Magento supports this behaviour (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319694/multiple-magento-stores-on-single-domain). 
You will then have www.example.com/storeA; www.example.com/storeB.
You should be aware, that some plugins have trouble when the store name is in the URL (for example: when redirected from payment gateway)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to this would be using customer groups, you can then apply different pricing to each product depending on how they registered, you could have different registration forms or a dropdown to select which group they apply to. That would be of course if you wanted to share other things like shipping etc..